# Range slider with variable max value

Tags: javascript

I have a ranged slider that can be be set on variable max values. 40, 60, 80, 200 etc. I'm Javascript to set the background of the slider element to a certain color based on the slider value.

```
const slider = document.getElementById('myRange')
slider.addEventListener('input', function () {  
  const sliderValue = slider.value
  const color = 'linear-gradient(to right, #2B73CC ' + sliderValue + '%, #fff 0%)'
  slider.style.background = color
}
```

This only works if the max value is set to 100. Since I'm using the `slider.value` as a `%` to style the background of the slider.

How would I change the value of `sliderValue` to reflect the actual value is `%`?

Example: the max of the range slider is set to 40. When the user scrolls to the end of the slider the value is 40. Now it passes `40%` to my background, filling the slider bar for 40%.

I need some way to set the `sliderValue` to 100% if the `slider.value` is equal to the max value set on the range slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the `value` by the `max` and multiply by `100`.

```js
const onSliderChange = (e) => {
  const
    slider         = e.target,
    container      = slider.parentElement,
    { value, max } = slider,
    percentage     = value / max * 100,
    color          = `linear-gradient(to right, #2B73CC ${percentage}%, #fff 0%)`;
  container.style.background = color;
};

const
  sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.slider-container'),
  slider          = sliderContainer.querySelector('.slider');

slider.addEventListener('input', onSliderChange);
```

```css
.slider-container .slider {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="40" value="10" class="slider">
</div>
```

Comment: Funny, did it just a bit different but the result is the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Took my brain about all the energy it has to solve this. Math is not my strongest point. But:

`console.log(sliderValue / (this.sliderValues.max / 100))` should work.